# How can we transfer the logs form the running container to other server using Rsysnc?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, docker

I have already tried to publish the logs to the host machine(using docker run -v src:/des) now I want to transfer the logs to a different server

Commands I've used :

- rsync -u -avze ssh source/* example.com:/des/logs

  > rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)
  >   rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.9]
  >   rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
  >   rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(1532) [sender=3.0.9]

Already checked the source and destination paths but it still says the same.

---

2. If the host server 1 can communicate with server 2, then the Docker container running on top of server 01 it should be able to communicate with server 2. (Is this a correct statement?)
3. Is there any way of using the Linux utilities we can able to manage the logs without using other tools like Splunk

Comment: Tried `docker logs ${container}`?

Comment: @xenoid that is when your on the host server we can use that command but not on the different servers

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, that’s why you’re getting the error message:

```
“No such file or directory (2) rsync error”
```

The correct syntax is:

```
$ rsync  <options>  /source host:/dest
```

E.g

```
$ rsync -avz /source host:/dest
```

If you must specify custom port for ssh, use quotes for this, example is below:

```
$ rsync -e "ssh -p port"  <options> /source host:/dest
```

Also, check the ownership of the source directory, it should be user doing rsync else fails to sync.

Comment: It's working fine I am looking for  If the host server 1 can communicate with server 2, then the Docker container running on top of server 01 it should be able to communicate with server 2. (Is this a correct statement?)

Is there any way of using the Linux utilities we can able to manage the logs without using other tools like Splunk